# python sqlalchemy filter records that all the keys in a list appear in either of two fileds

Tags: python-2.7, flask-sqlalchemy

I was writing a simple BBS system with flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy. I want to implement a simple search function, which finds out all the records that all the keys in a given list are appeared in either of the two fields: 'title' and 'content'.  Here is how I do now:

```
# Topic is just a table and has some fields, such as title and content.
keys = keywords.split(' ')
all_topics = set(Topic.query.filter(
    and_(*[Topic.title.like("%" + k + "%") for k in keys])).all())
content_topics = set(Topic.query.filter(
    and_(*[Topic.content.like("%" + k + "%") for k in keys])).all())

# Remove duplicated search result, because the keywords may 
# occur in both title and content.
all_topics.update(content_topics)
```

But it's not so much suitable.  Because for one specified key it can appear either in title or content.

---

Update:

To make it more clear, I'd like to give a simple example.  The records in db looks like:

```
 Id |      Title          | Content   
 ---|       ---           | ---  
| 1 | This is a demo      | For test  
| 2 | This is also a demo | Again  
| 3 | This demo test      | HaHa
```

When I search for "**This test**", my current function just return me the `record 3`.  But I want `record 1` to be returned too.  What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to bother with Python sets - let the database do the work. All the keywords must appear in column title, or in column content or in the concatenation of columns title and content.

See self-contained example below. You'll need to adjust how you define the hybrid expression according to the database you use. As the example is using SQLite I've used a `literal_column` to concatenate the two fields into one string but other databases might have a `concat` function.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import or_, and_
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.sql import literal_column
from sqlalchemy.sql import expression, functions

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


def build_db():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    _items = [
        {'title': 'This is a demo one', 'content': 'For test'},
        {'title': 'This is also a demo two', 'content': 'Again'},
        {'title': 'This demo test three', 'content': 'HaHa'},
    ]

    for _item in _items:
        _topic = Topic(**_item)
        db.session.add(_topic)

    db.session.commit()


class Topic(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=255), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=255), nullable=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def title_content(self):
        return '{0} {1}'.format(self.title, self.content)

    @title_content.expression
    def title_content(cls):
        return literal_column('title || " " || content')

TEMPLATE = '''
    {% for topic in all_topics %}
        <h1>{{topic.title}}</h1>
        <p>{{topic.content}}</p>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
'''


@app.route('/')
def index():

    keys = 'This test'.split(' ')

    _title_conditions = []
    for name in keys:
        _title_conditions.append(Topic.title.ilike('%{}%'.format(name)))

    _content_conditions = []
    for name in keys:
        _content_conditions.append(Topic.content.ilike('%{}%'.format(name)))

    _content_concat_topic_conditions = []
    for name in keys:
        _content_concat_topic_conditions.append(Topic.title_content.ilike('%{}%'.format(name)))

    all_topics = Topic.query.filter(or_(
        and_(*_content_conditions).self_group(),
        and_(*_title_conditions).self_group(),
        and_(*_content_concat_topic_conditions).self_group(),
    )).all()

    for _topic in all_topics:
        print _topic.title

    return render_template_string(TEMPLATE, all_topics=all_topics)

@app.before_first_request
def first_request():
    build_db()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=7777)
```

Comment: Sorry for not so clear about my question.  I update it just now, hope you can get my idea and help me out.

Comment: Got it!   Hybrid Attributes is the key!  Thanks very much for your detailed demo.